# Show / Hide ComposeView in XML - Android, Kotlin, Jetpack Compose, Interoperability

Tags: android, kotlin, interop, android-jetpack-compose, onclicklistener

I am adding a ComposeView to my XML layout.  The ComposeView is a widget that will stay hidden until a button is clicked (button is in XML).

I have tried a number of things, but the way the app is setup my ComposeView widget does not recompose after the the button click.

Code

`DetailsWidget` is where the `onClickListener` is set for each widget

```
class DetailsWidget : ListingDetailsWidget {
...
    override fun buildView(inflater: LayoutInflater) : View? {
        ...
        val expandButton = baseView.findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_expand)
        val buttonContainer = baseView.findViewById<View>(R.id.expand_button_container)
        val tableContainerComposeview = baseView.findViewById<View>(R.id.table_container_compose_view) <- I added this line to existing code

    tableView.post {
        if (!tableView.isExpanded) {
            buttonContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            expandButton.setOnClickListener {
                tableView.isExpanded = true
                buttonContainer.visibility = View.GONE
                DetailsWidgetViewModel().onTableViewExpanded() <- I added this line to existing code

                }
            }
        }
        return baseView
    }
}
```

`DetailsWidgetViewModel`

```
class DetailsWidgetViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _showDetailsWidget = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val showDetailsWidget: StateFlow<Boolean> = _showDetailsWidget.asStateFlow()

    fun onTableViewExpanded() {
        _showDetailsWidget.value = true
    }
}
```

`JetpackComposeWidget`

```
@Parcelize
@Serializable
data class JetpackComposeWidgetData(
    ...
) : ListingDetailsWidget() {
    override fun buildView(inflater: LayoutInflater): View {
        val binding = ViewDetailWidgetDetailsBinding.inflate(inflater, null, false)
        val view = binding.root

        binding.tableContainerComposeView.setContent {
            JetpackComposeWidget(data = this)
        }

        return view
    }
}

@Composable
fun JetpackComposeWidget(data: JetpackComposeWidgetData) {
    val showDetailsWidgetState: Boolean by DetailsWidgetViewModel().showDetailsWidget.collectAsState()

if (showDetailsWidgetState) {
    LdpWidgetTheme {
        Surface(
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
            modifier = Modifier.clickable { DetailsWidgetViewModel().onTableViewExpanded() }
        ) {
            Column(
                Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp),
            ) {
                data.title?.let {
                    Text(
                        text = it,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4,
                    )
                }
                data.sections.mapIndexed { index, section -> Section(section, index == 0) }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Is there a better way to show / hide a ComposeView in XML?

What I've tried:

- Add to ComposeView XML `android:onClick='onTableViewExpanded'`
- Add to ComposeView XML `android:visibility:"gone"` then setting the ComposeView to `View.VISIBLE` in the `setOnClickListener` code block
- Call an event listener on button click
- Recompose on button click using `_showDetailsWidget.copy(value = true)`
- Live Data and Mutable State instead of `MutableStateFlow`

Comment: Trying another approach with `LiveData`.  Does `LiveData` force a recomposition?  The boolean appears to be changing from false to true.  My guess it that the widget is not recomposing after the change.